# How to disable template auto-format in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, format, templates

I have a template (`sleep`) in Eclipse 4.2.1 that should expand to

```
try { Thread.sleep(1000); } catch (Exception e) {}
```

I want Eclipse to add it as one line, just as I put it in the template. However, Eclipse autoformats it after inserting to:

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

I have tried `@formatter:off`, but that does not work. I have code cleanup switched off.

Is there any way to disable formatting for all templates, since the only templates I use are one-liners anyway?

Answer (score 3):

`Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Templates`, as you know.

There is the list of templates, defaults given by Eclipse, and yours.

At the bottom of the dialog, in Eclipse Juno (4.2), I see a checkbox `Use code formatter`.
Unchecking it deactivates the auto-format at insertion time.

Alas, it is a global setting, applied to all template... But well, that's what you look for, anyway.

[EDIT] I see the same checkbox in Indigo (3.7).